# Reveal div if no click on a certain other div for more than x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have in javascript a code that currently does well what I want :

- The alert message first appear after 7 seconds
- Remove the alert when div TARGET is clicked or touched

But I don't manage to do this: once a user has clicked on a target (that's already operational), but then I want the alert message to reappear after, **every time the user has not clicked on .target div for more than 5 seconds**.

I'm rephrasing it to be more clear: I want the message to first appear after 7 seconds, then each time the user click on.target, the message should disappear. BUT if he does not click for more than 5 seconds on .target, the message should REappear

How to do this ?

**html**

```
<section id="alert-msg" style="visibility: hidden"> 
  <div>my message</div>
</section>
```

**Javascript**

```
//1. message only appear after 7 sec
function showIt2() {
    document.getElementById("alert-msg").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  setTimeout(showIt2, 7000); 

// 2. alert message disappear when .target div is clicked
  $('.target').on('click touchstart', function(){
    $("#alert-msg").remove();
  });
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/111994re/3/

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle with what you have so far

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `id="alert-msg"` and `$("#alert")`?

Comment: yes typo i'll correct it

Comment: Yeah, a reduced-test-case jsFiddle would be fantastic. There's lots of different places this error could be.

Comment: it's not an error, i don't manage to do the last thing I mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this revision: https://jsfiddle.net/111994re/7/

I've added setTimeout inside of your onclick
I've set visibility to hidden instead of removing it (removing it you can't unhide it at that point, you would have to re-add)

```
//1. message only appear after 7 sec
function showIt2() {
    document.getElementById("alert-msg").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  setTimeout(showIt2, 7000); 

// 2. alert message disappear when .target div is clicked
  $('.target').on('click touchstart', function(){
    document.getElementById("alert-msg").style.visibility = "hidden";
    setTimeout(showIt2, 5000);
  });
```

Comment: Changed my question to be clearer. i need  alert to REappear every 5 seconds if user has not clicked any .target

Comment: This will show 5 seconds after the click regardless of when the user lets go of the mouse. For example: if they click the mouse and keep it down it will still reappear in 5 seconds.

Comment: @jnoreiga, They have to click on an element with the `target` class, which is the only time the message disappears, and yes it is on `touchstart`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now, alert appears after x seconds. Then, if the user clicks target, the timer resets and alert appears again after x seconds indefinitely.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<section id="alert-msg"> 
    <div style="display:none;">Alert!</div>
</section>

<div class="target">Target</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//1. message only appear after 7 sec
function showIt2() {
    if( $('#alert-msg') ){
        $('#alert-msg div').fadeOut();
        $('#alert-msg div').fadeIn();
    }
  }
  var show = setInterval(showIt2, 5000); 

// 2. alert message disappear when .target div is clicked
  $('.target').on('click touchstart', function(){
    $("#alert-msg div").hide();
    clearInterval(show);
    show = setInterval(showIt2, 5000); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Changed my question to be clearer. i need  alert to REappear every 5 seconds if user has not clicked any .target

Comment: Ah- ok. I'll rewrite my answer

Comment: Ok, it's updated. You have to use setInterval and clearInterval

Comment: trying it here: https://jsfiddle.net/111994re/6/. it makes a strange thing .the hello goes down, down, and down...:)

Comment: Yes, did you want it to disappear and then reappear?

Comment: I want the message to first appear after 7 seconds, then if user click on.target, the message should disappear. BUT AFTER THAT, if he does not click for more than 5 seconds on .target, the message should REappear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104666/discussion-between-alain-nisam-and-mathieu).

Answer (score 1):

There where some typing error

```js
//1. message only appear after 7 sec
function showIt2() {
    document.getElementById("alert-msg").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  setTimeout(showIt2, 7000); 

// 2. alert message disappear when .target div is clicked
  $('.target').on('click touchstart', function(){
    $("#alert-msg").remove();
});
```

```html
<section id="alert-msg" style="visibility: hidden"> 
  <div>my message</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/111994re/10/

```
   //1. message only appear after 7 sec
function showIt2() {
    $("#alert-msg").show();
  }
  setTimeout(showIt2, 7000); 

// 2. alert message disappear when .target div is clicked
  $('.target').on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
  $("#alert-msg").hide(); 
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);

  }).on("mouseup touchstop", function(e) {
    this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {

          showIt2();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: now even if I click on .target, the message does not disappear

Comment: Your original request before you edited it stated that you wanted it to remove the alert when the target is clicked for more than 5 seconds. My example removes it if you press on the target for more than 5 seconds. Your question is confusing.

Comment: i still want to keep the method that does: if the user click on .target the message should disappear. (was in my initial code) but it's not working anymore on yours. I want both things

Comment: Ok I updated my solution. it will show the message after 7 seconds. Then it will hide it when the user clicks target. 5 seconds after the user stops clicking target it will reappear.

Comment: the message never appears (he should initially after 7 sec)